# C# Entity Framework Core - Throw an error when child item gets added to a soft-deleted parent OnSave

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, soft-delete

I have bunch of tables that contain `DeletedAt` column that's used for a `soft-delete` feature. I've implemented most of the logic and everything works correctly except for one issue **where it allows to add a child record to a soft-deleted parent record**. I'd like to throw an exception when `DbContext.OnSave()` runs and finds that the parent record (`foreignKey`) is actually `soft-deleted`.

Is there any way I can inject a filter or something that can check for that parent `DeletedAt` field before adding the child element?

I do have few ideas but kinda painful and require to loop through all foreignKeys in the child model and checks if that parent object has `DeletedAt` set or not.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should add a global filter on loading to filter deleted entity. So you don't have access the soft-deleted parent on loading to be able to add any child

Comment: If the parent entity has the foreign key field, then you can catch those by modified state

Comment: @qazwsx123 - I've already added that global filter. It works on getting the records.

Comment: Don't couple yourself with the "frameworks" (such as Entity Framework) that do not yield non-trivial benefits to the rest of the system. Otherwise, you end up with "Entity Frameworky" solutions and these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did find a solution and it's not that bad, here's the implementation for anyone who's interested (before your code hits the `DbContext.SaveChanges()`) in the `DbContext` file:

```
var entry = Entry(childModel);
foreach(var prop in entry.CurrentValues.Properties)
{
    // Handle FKs only
    if(!prop.IsForeignKey()) continue;

    var fkValue = entry.CurrentValues[prop.Name];
    
    // Handle nullable properties and skip the checks if the value is null
    if(prop.IsColumnNullable() && fkValue == null) continue;

    // If value is null or 0 then break
    if(fkValue == null || (int)fkValue == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Must contain a value.");
    }
    
    // Get the FK
    var fk = prop.GetContainingForeignKeys().FirstOrDefault();
    if(fk == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("FK constraint is not available.");
    }

    // If parent is not available or deleted
    var parent = Find(fk.PrincipalEntityType.ClrType, new object[]{fkValue});
    if(parent == null)
    {
        throw new Exception($"The entered FK value ({fkValue}) is not valid.");
    }
}
```

`Find` method actually has a global filter that checks if the `DeletedAt` field is set or not. If the record doesn't exist, this will fail. This should be dynamic enough to handle all FKs in a table.

Answer (score 0):

One option available to EF Core, and somewhat painfully in EF6 is to fully encapsulate the collection so that items are added *through* the parent, allowing you to control whether items can be added or not depending on the parent's current state.

See: https://ardalis.com/encapsulated-collections-in-entity-framework-core/

The gist being to restrict the adding of Children to a method called `AddChild(child)` on the parent which asserts the parent isn't soft-deleted.